# tensorflow -- how to get an array of a "weight variable"

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying change some of the weights by assignment a sets of weights to another set. However, I got the following error. It seems what I did is wrong for doing that sort of thing.

I would be grateful if you could tell me what I need to do in order to change weights.

```
<ipython-input-1-59feba7d7a35> in draw(n_r, n_c)
     72                         plt.subplot(2*ROW, COL, 2*row*COL + COL+col+1)
     73                         plt.title('O:%02d' % (i+1))
---> 74                         y_value = y.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x: data, keep_prob: 1.0, r_keep_prob: 1.0})
     75                         plt.imshow(y_value.reshape((28, 28)))
     76                         plt.tick_params(labelbottom="off")

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    458 
    459     """
--> 460     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    461 
    462 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   2908                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
   2909                        "graph.")
-> 2910   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   2911 
   2912 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict)
    354                          + e.message)
    355             e.args = (e.message,)
--> 356             raise e
    357           np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
    358           if subfeed_t.op.type == 'Placeholder':

ValueError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name '0' looks like an (invalid) Operation name, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".
```

Comment: One of the feed_dict keys is a string `0`, and it should be a Tensor

Comment: That's your USEFUL ANSWER, Yaroslav, to quote (almost verbatim) an error message that the interpreter gave him?

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner thats about as good an advice as it gets, considering that the OP has not posted any code.